# Написать программу, определяющую попадает ли точка в область

Tags: python, математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как описать условие, при котором входные параметры (float координата x и y) будут определены, принадлежат ли закрашенной области

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это 2 четвертькруга, один как часть круга со серединой `[0, 0]` и радиусом `1`, второй как часть круга со серединой `[0, -1]`, тоже с радиусом `1`.

Чтобы точка `[x, y]` попала в первый **круг**, должна исполнить неравенство

```
x**2 + y**2 <= 1
```

Для второго круга:

```
x**2 + (y+1)**2 <= 1
```

Хотели только подсказку.

Попробуйте самостоятельно добавить условия (ограничение), чтобы точка находилась тоже в соответствующей **четверти** круга — это уже простые неравенства типа
*«координата более или равна / менее или равна какому-то числу».*

Comment: Спасибо, но в этом я и затрудняюсь, как попасть именно в нужные четверти

Comment: Я дополнил мой ответ — достаточно?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @grayhound99, не стоит. :-)